# How do I get all the information regarding the header of an audio file?

Tags: header, ascii, wav

How do I get all the information regarding the header of an audio file, so it can be displayed in a readable format like ASCII values?

The audio file maybe of any format, most preferably `.wav` format.

EDIT:- OS can be windows 8.1 or ubuntu. I actually have to understand all the properties of the file like whether it is mono or stereo, its encoding, etc. maybe specifically `.wav` file, i would say.

I have knowledge about the C++ language, so that would be better.

Comment: This question is currently too broad. Please specify which language, OS, etc. this is for.

Comment: Also... What **exactly** is the problem you are facing? keep in mind that header files for different formats have different specs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very powerful command you can use in a bash script: `sox`.
To get all the info you need about a wav file, you just have to run:

```
soxi file.wav
```

and you'll get something like:

```
Input File     : 'file.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 8000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:02:08.40 = 1027236 samples ~ 9630.34 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 2.05M
Bit Rate       : 128k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

`sox` is available for Windows as well, although I have never used there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFPROBE utility from **FFMPEG**: http://ffmpeg.org/

"ffprobe" gathers information from multimedia streams and prints it in human- and machine-readable fashion.
For example it can be used to check the format of the container used by a multimedia stream 
and the format and type of each media stream contained in it.

**Code**

```
ffprobe -i <file_name>
ffprobe -i myfile.wav
```

**Output will look something like this**

```
Input #0, wav, from 'myfile.wav':
  Duration: 00:04:16.88, bitrate: 16 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: g729 ([131][0][0][0] / 0x0083), 8000 Hz, 2 channels, s16p, 16 kb/s
```

**Output Explanation:**

- g729 is encoding type here.
- 16 kb/s is the bit-rate.
- 2 channels
- Sample rate 8000 Hz

**For detailed information**

`ffprobe -i <file_name> -show_streams`